# Custom array-valued Hive UDF in Python?

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, hive

Is there a way to create an array-valued Hive UDF in Python? The UDF I'm interested in will take 3 values: initial, final, and step, and would return an array of in-between values. Thanks. Jython is fine. Java is not (for now).

Answer (score 0):

You can use list with slice. The detail explanation is given on http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html